# Reference data from another table

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

I am creating a database table and want to make sure that data in one of the column is always bounded by data in a column of another table. for example:

Table_1 has Column_1
Column_1 can have values:
v1
v2
v3
v4
v2
v3

Now I am trying to create Table_2 with Column_3
and want to make sure that values in this column is always a subset of Table_1:Column_1

Is there a constraint I can apply to achieve this?

Comment: Just as a general comment, this model is not denormalised and therefore you are working against the natural model of a relational database. If the model were normalised, with a third table containing a single primary key of unique values in Table_1.Column_1, the solution would be obvious. Is there a reason why you aren't normalizing this data?

Comment: I am working on a schema spread across various modules, s there are multiple tables like table 1, while it may be possible to normalize some of them, but won't be able to do it for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle and PostgreSQL, use a check constraint

eg, in Oracle:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_3
ADD CONSTRAINT my_name
CHECK
    (column_3 in 
        (SELECT Column_1 FROM Table_1))
```

This also works with PostgreSQL

In SQL Server and DB2, I believe, you have to create a function that does the actual test, but otherwise it's the same. The function would have a single argument (column_3's value) and return EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_1 WHERE Column_1 = argument).

Unfortunately, in MySQL you will need to use on insert and update triggers

Comment: But column_1 is not the primary key of table_1, and not required to be unique either.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Which DB are you using or targeting?

Comment: Oracle 11g R2 but ideally I am looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Table_1.Column_1` unique?

- If **yes**, just make it a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE, then reference it from FOREIGN KEY on the `Table_2.Column_3`.
- If **no** (as apparently implied by your example), make a FK from `Table_2` to `Table_1`'s primary key. The `Table_2.Column_3` won't even exist, instead you'll get the values of `Table_1.Column_1` by JOIN-ing the two tables. You can put that JOIN in a VIEW to make it appear (to the client applications) as if the `Table_2.Column_3` actually exists.